# Left CTRL, ALT and SUPER do not work anymore

Tags: gnome, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I've been having trouble with my Ubuntu Laptop.
At first it seemed that ALT is pressed all the time (especially while using Eclipse). Somehow that fixed itself after I tried a lot of things.
Now my left <kbd>CTRL</kbd>,<kbd>ALT</kbd> and <kbd>SUPER</kbd> (Windows) Key do not work anymore. When I'm under Region & Language and check my keyboard, every button lights up, except for those three.

Does anybody have a clue how to fix this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me:
go to **settings** > **Devices** > **Keyboard**, and do ***Reset All***!
I do not know why the setting were different, perhaps it because I did the upgrade from Ubuntu 16.4!